# Difficulties install Drush using composer

Tags: drush

I have tried to install Drush on OSX 10.9 but it doesn’t seem to have worked. In terminal ‘drush status’ gives

> -bash: drush: command not found

I have followed the instructions on http://whaaat.com/installing-drush-7-using-composer

Composer’s directory seems to be correct as my .bash_profile contains:

```
export PATH="$Trotter/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Drush exists in the vendor folder of composer

[image: Directory structure to Drush]

When I tried to install Drush via composer the feedback seemed to suggest it had worked:

```
Pauls-iMac:~ Trotter$ composer self-update
Updating to version 8e9659bd8317ad3f623c4d17940380443cf8772c.
    Downloading: 100%         
Use composer self-update --rollback to return to version 1.0.0-alpha9
Pauls-iMac:~ Trotter$ composer global require drush/drush:7.*
Changed current directory to /Users/Trotter/.composer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing pear/console_table (1.2.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v2.7.1)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing symfony/yaml (v2.7.1)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing d11wtq/boris (v1.0.8)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing drush/drush (6.5.0)
  - Installing drush/drush (7.0.0)
    Downloading: 100%         

pear/console_table suggests installing pear/Console_Color2 (>=0.1.2)
symfony/var-dumper suggests installing ext-symfony_debug ()
d11wtq/boris suggests installing ext-pcntl (*)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Pauls-iMac:~ Trotter$ drush status
-bash: drush: command not found
```

(Note I had previously tried to install Drush 6 but hadn't got this to work either)

I would appreciate any advice on what is going wrong here.

Comment: Is `$Trotter` set above that line in the bash script? Any reason not to use the standard `~`? Have you re-`source`d the bash profile since changing it? I think your question just comes down to "why isn't composer's global path in my session's global path", which should hopefully be easy to figure out (and isn't really related to Drupal/Drush as such, in case you're trying to find a solution from either of those systems' points of view)

Comment: @Paul  What php version are you running ?

Comment: @Clive my basic command prompt when opening terminal is: Pauls-iMac:~ Trotter$

Comment: @darol I am running PHP version 5.5.11

Comment: Try changing that to `export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"` (assuming you run Drush under that user account), or `export PATH="/Users/<username>/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`. Make sure you `source ~/.bash_profile` after making changes unless you start a new terminal session

Comment: @Clive export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH" worked and now `drush stauts` gives good feedback on the Drush version etc. Thanks. Would you like to add that as an answer and I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the .bash_profile to the following worked:

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Now drush status gives good feedback on the Drush version etc. Thanks to Clive for suggesting this.

Comment: It helped me too, but I am too new, and too noob in Ubuntu to know why... Can someone please explain the mechanism behind it to me and further readers? Thanks,

Comment: Type "path in bash profile" into Google @benos. If you don't know what a bash profile, search for "bash profile" instead. These concepts aren't going to be explained on a site for questions about Drupal, they're unrelated

Comment: Sure I will look for it right now --- That suggestion by itself helps me very much, thank you,

Comment: @Clive, after I've closed the terminal via "exit" command I needed to run this again...  Is there a way to change it permanently ? I didn't have time to dive to it from yesterday; I just need a way to change the bash profile permanently so I wouldn't need to run it time and again...

Answer (score 2):

The linked manual may be outdated. Please follow the steps below.

### Installing `drush`

#### via Phar binary

Download latest stable release using the command below:

**OS X/Unix**:

```
sudo wget -O /usr/local/bin/drush http://files.drush.org/drush.phar
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/drush
```

**Linux**:

```
sudo install <(curl http://files.drush.org/drush.phar) /usr/local/bin/drush
```

**Windows and other**

Download manually at https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases

#### via Composer

If you'd like to install `drush` globally (for all users) and `/usr/local/bin` is already in your `PATH`, try installing using the following syntax:

```
sudo COMPOSER_HOME=/opt/drush COMPOSER_BIN_DIR=/usr/local/bin COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR=/opt/drush/7 composer require drush/drush:7
```

or:

```
sudo COMPOSER_HOME=/var/lib/composer COMPOSER_BIN_DIR=/usr/local/bin COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR=/var/lib/composer/vendor composer require drush/drush:7
```

Change `drush/drush:7` into `drush/drush:dev-master` for the latest development version.

#### via Homebrew (OS X)

Run:

```
brew install drush
```

---

See: [Install/Upgrade a global Drush](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the simplest way is to install it with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)

Once brew is installed and working simple type `brew install drush`.

Comment: But you can't install the latest drush using homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

My .bash_profile contains exactly

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

and my drush lies here (Acquia DevDesktop)

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/DevDesktop/drush"
```

Answer (score 0):

This article for installation of Composer with Drush included can be useful:

https://www.pcextreme.nl/community/d/138-drush-installation-for-drupal-shared-hosting