# How do I install Drush?

Tags: drush

I am struggling on how to install Drush.

I have only seen [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/162109/difficulties-install-drush-using-composer) as a similar question which doesn't answer my question.

Drush's own tutorial from [here](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/#install-a-site-local-drush), doesn't offer much. Its a little vague actually.

I have executed this line in my powershell windows 8:

> wget https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/8.0.0-rc3/drush.phar

And it goes through smoothly.
When I execute the next line:

> php drush.phar core-status

I get this error:

> Could not open input file: Drush.phar

Other than that I thought by downloading the windows zip package 7.0.0 I would be able to simply install, but that didn't work either. I mean, I unzipped it but there was no executable file or anything to install. Maybe I did something wrong there.

Comment: There have been some issues working on Windows support for Drush in the issue queue, but I don't know that anyone has tried to use the .phar on Windows. This might be a better discussed in the issue queue.

Comment: @asma22 fair enough, I guess it's not an ideal tutorial for Drupal 7.

Comment: @NoSssweat edited comment: It seems that part of the confusion is that you do need a composer which isn't mentioned in an obvious way, it only says that for Drupal 8 and that you need to write down runas... so that you would have the appropriate privilege